# Find next element of a given class starting from $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have a page that has multiple comment section. Please see here: http://bluepresley.com/tna/question/where-is-the-best-soup-curry-in-sapporo/

This is a question and answer website, and, as you see on the page, there is a Grey "Write a reply..." box for the question as well as for each answer.

I want to hide those by default, only showing them when someone clicks on the generated "show comments" button.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Show/Hide Comments
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Get #comment-section div
    var commentsDiv = jQuery('.dwqa-comments');
    // Only do this work if that div isn't empty
    if (commentsDiv.length) {
        // Hide #comment-section div by default
        jQuery(commentsDiv).hide();
        // Append a link to show/hide
        jQuery('<button/>')
                .attr('class', 'toggle-comments')
                .attr('href', '#')
                .html('Show Comments ')
                .insertBefore(commentsDiv);
        // Encase button in #toggle-comments-container div
        jQuery('.toggle-comments').wrap(jQuery('<div/>', {
            id: 'toggle-comments-container'
        }));
        // When show/hide is clicked
        jQuery('.toggle-comments').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(jQuery(this).next('.dwqa-comments'));
            // Show/hide the div using jQuery's toggle()
            jQuery(this).next('.dwqa-comments').toggle('slow', function() {
                // change the text of the anchor
                //var anchor = jQuery('.toggle-comments');
                //var anchorText = anchor.html() == 'Show Comments ' ? 'Hide Comments ' : 'Show Comments ';
                //jQuery(anchor).html(anchorText);
            });
        });

    } // End of commentsDiv.length
}); // End of Show/Hide Comments
```

I'm using the `.next()` method to try to target the very next element of dwqa-comments using `this` as I've seen in many tutorials, but I have no idea why it's not working.

Thought?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're running into? What were you expecting to happen and what happened instead? Is it possible to set up an example of the issue in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the .next() because the comments is the next sibling of the clicked element's parent.

Also `toggle-comments-container` should be a class because there can be multiple elements in the page and id must be unique

So try

```
// Show/Hide Comments
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Get #comment-section div
    //added the has() clause so that only comments with actual comment elements are targeted
    var commentsDiv = $('.dwqa-comments').has('.comment');
    // Only do this work if that div isn't empty
    if (commentsDiv.length) {
        // Hide #comment-section div by default
        $(commentsDiv).hide();
        // Append a link to show/hide
        $('<button/>')
            .attr('class', 'toggle-comments')
            .attr('href', '#')
            .html('Show Comments ')
            .insertBefore(commentsDiv);
        // Encase button in #toggle-comments-container div
        $('.toggle-comments').wrap($('<div/>', {
            //use class because id of an element must be unique
            class: 'toggle-comments-container'
        }));
        // When show/hide is clicked
        $('.toggle-comments').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log($(this).next('.dwqa-comments'));
            // Show/hide the div using $'s toggle()
            //need to access the parent because the `dwqa-comments` element is the next sibling of the clicked `toggle-comments`'s parent
            $(this).parent().next('.dwqa-comments').toggle('slow', function () {
                // change the text of the anchor
                //var anchor = $('.toggle-comments');
                //var anchorText = anchor.html() == 'Show Comments ' ? 'Hide Comments ' : 'Show Comments ';
                //$(anchor).html(anchorText);
            });
        });

    } // End of commentsDiv.length
}); // End of Show/Hide Comments
```

Comment: Ah, it was my misunderstanding of how next works. I thought that next with a selector would target that next selector in the DOM no matter where it was in the hierarchy. Thanks for that.